# Run-time error '1004': Unable to set line style property of border class in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Run-time error '1004': Unable to set line style property of border class in VBA.

while running code for setting the border of range then getting run time error and same code is running successfully on different system.

The code is:

```
Range("A7:A" & LastRow).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar issue many times.
All the times the only problem was i needed to unlock the sheet.

Can you check if your worksheets are protected or if your workbook is protected?
In that case you need to unlock the Worksheet/Workbook for your code to function properly.

Comment: should not be downvoted: it is a very general answer/fix for such problems, but could indeed be the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

`Activesheet.Range("A7:A" & LastRow).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous`

The error probably comes because you are not referring the `WorkSheet` of the range or because the worksheet is locked.