# VBA: How to Automatically Include Cell Borders Without Error (Runtime 1004) Line Style

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

So this a question about the same big project my others are.

I am now just tidying up some formatting and essentially want a sub (that I can call from another) which will automatically add the borders I need around the new data being posted to the sheet.

I recorded the macro of adding the borders (and changed the range to one that is variable - RowToPasteTo) and all was working well.

I tried to call it from another piece of code and it went haywire, now giving me an error of:

`Run-Time error '1004':`

`Unable to set the LineStyle Property of the Borders class`

As the error mentions, it seems to be an error with the `.LineStyle` but I am using the same style as what their recorder gave me.

How can I get this working again so that is completes all borders?

EDIT: Forgot to add the code - sorry!

```
Sub Borders()

Dim RowToPasteTo As Long

With Sheets(4)

 RowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Range("B" & RowToPasteTo & ":" & "Z" & RowToPasteTo).Select
  With Selection.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ThemeColor = 3
    .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
    .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

EDIT 2: This piece of code is to insert the borders when each new row of data is moved to this sheet (grid marks are off, as the borders are only to be shown on the lines with data.

I have tried all amendments so far suggested and am still receiving errors when running the above code alone.

I have now also created a blank sheet (and adjusted the sheets number accordingly) and I receive a different error there.

The (minimised) code that will later call this piece if as follows:

```
Sub ToTank()
Dim RowToPasteTo As Long
        RowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Sheets(4).Unprotect
        .Range("A" & RowToPasteTo & ":" & "Z" & RowToPasteTo).Locked = False
Call Borders()

End Sub
```

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to give a lot more information including the code and what you have tried so far

Comment: So Sorry, completely forgot to add it! D'oh clearly need another coffee

Comment: Not your problem but some improvement, change: `Range("B" & RowToPasteTo & ":" & "Z" & RowToPasteTo).Select With Selection.Borders` for: `With Range("B" & RowToPasteTo & ":" & "Z" & RowToPasteTo).Borders` Also is a good idea to full qualify your ranges (workbook and sheet where that range belongs)

Comment: I completely agree. I probably should have mentioned  I have it qualified in another sub and was going to reference it but forgot - really not my morning aha

On note with your improvement Damian, VBA is returning a Compile error: Invalid Use of Property

Comment: `.Borders` require an argument (i.e.`.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)`), see [Borders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.borders)

Comment: Have a look at this. Not sure whether it's the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054857/run-time-error-1004-unable-to-set-line-style-property-of-border-class-in-vba

Comment: You are using a `With` inside another `With`. I think line `Range("B" & RowToPasteTo & ":" & "Z" & RowToPasteTo).Select` should have a dot at start, or it will take the range in whatever the activesheet is, instead of the range in sheet(4).

Comment: I did try your code in my  workbook and it works, doesn't change a thing because `.TintAndShade` overrides `.ThemeColor` and that leaves the cell the same way, but no errors at all on my sheet.

Comment: @MimiBeard could you please add the code calling this sub? because there are no errors when running it like this, and also what is your goal on adding borders? your sheet has no borders? Because this code inputs the default borders that come with the sheet, if you unchecked the square view has sense, otherwise it does not.

Comment: I am very confused! I have done all these amendments and its still coming up with the Line Style Error. 
Additionally I just created a new sheet (and then changed the with sheets number accordingly) and it comes up with a different error all together.

Comment: @MimiBeard I edited my answer with your new info, does my way work?

Comment: @Damian yep! It's beautiful thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something going on from the main sub calling the border sub. To avoid these kind of problems you need to full qualify all your ranges, another way is to do this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ToTank()

    Dim RowToPasteTo As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4) 'If the code runs for the same workbook the code is in
        RowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Unprotect
        Borders .Range("B" & RowToPasteTo & ":" & "Z" & RowToPasteTo) 'call the procedure inserting the borders passing the range you need
    End With

End Sub
Sub Borders(MyRange As Range)

    With MyRange.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 3
        .TintAndShade = -9.99786370433668E-02
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

End Sub
```

This way you can always call the `Borders` sub giving the range you want without any modifications. You could also make variables the `LineStyle` and all the properties you need by passing more arguments.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, `.Borders` require at least 1 argument to work. One way to achieve what you are trying to do is:

```vb
Sub Borders()

Dim RowToPasteTo As Long

With Sheets(4)

    RowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For X = 1 To 4
        With .Range("B" & RowToPasteTo & ":" & "Z" & RowToPasteTo).Borders(X)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 3
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    Next X
End With

End Sub
```

**Correction** as per @Damian's comment, though the above is perfectly usable as well:

```vb
Sub Borders()

Dim RowToPasteTo As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    RowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With .Range("B" & RowToPasteTo & ":" & "Z" & RowToPasteTo).Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 3
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

See [Borders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.borders) for more details.

Comment: I think that the OP's want to mark all the edges, so there is no need to go 1 by 1, without writting one specific border VBA will print them all. Using the left/right/top/bottom is to scope them, if you need all of them there is no need.

Comment: Thanks Damian, you are correct... my experience with formatting is somewhat limited, as I avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: No problem I hate formatting also, actually I just found out that by trying the OP's code hahaha...